# Why template arguments type can't be deduced from a field within a class?

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename Func>
class FuncWrapper {
    Func func;
    std::string name;

public:

    FuncWrapper(Func func, std::string name) : func(func), name(std::move(name)) {}

    template<typename ...Args>
    auto operator()(Args ...args) {
        std::cout << "Entering " + name + '\n';
        func(args...);
        std::cout << "Exiting " + name + '\n';
    }
};

template<typename Func>
auto makeFuncWrapper(Func func, std::string name) {
    return FuncWrapper<Func>(func, name);
}

int main() {

    auto helloWorld = []() { std::cout << "Hello World\n"; };
    auto printTwoNums = [](int a, int b) { std::cout << a << ' ' << b << '\n'; };

//    FuncWrapper(helloWorld, "helloWorld")(); // Error.
//    FuncWrapper(printTwoNums, "printTwoNums")(4, 5); // Error.

    makeFuncWrapper(helloWorld, "helloWorld")();
    std::cout << '\n';
    makeFuncWrapper(printTwoNums, "printTwoNums")(4, 5);

}
```

Output:

```
Entering helloWorld
Hello World
Exiting helloWorld

Entering printTwoNums
4 5
Exiting printTwoNums
```

I'm trying to make a function wrapper that adds an additional functionality to a function. In the class `FuncWrapper`, there is a field called `func` with the type of the template argument (`Func`). When I try to pass a lambda to the constructor, I get an error saying that I'm missing some template arguments. Whereas if I use a helper function, it deduces the type normally. Why isn't it deducing the type of the argument when I pass the lambda to the constructor? And why the function can deduce but not the constructor of a class? Also what is a possible solution? And is there any possible improvement to this code or a better way to achieve the same behavior?

Comment: What version of C++ are you using?

Comment: If you can upgrade to a C++17 compliant compiler, you can actually get what you want.  I've closed this as a dupe to a Q that explains the situation an also links to another question that gives full details about c++17's CTAD feature.